# Notebook with broken graphics card vncing to raspberry?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, vnc, headless

I have a moderately fast notebook with a broken graphics card and a totally functionable raspberry 3B. I had the idea of installing a linux system onto the notebook,  install Kodi into it, start a VNC-Server, connect to this server via the raspberry and then watch my video movies on my TV which is connected to the raspberry's HDMI. 
I understand I can use that notebook as a headless server, but is my idea of "rerouting" the kodi genius or pure madness?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of VNC and Video is not a marriage made in heaven: VNC has no concept of Video acceleration, it will just transfer changed pixels. So I doubt, that a RasPi as display will be able to keep up with the pixel rate.

What might work though, is streaming the video: Transcode to e.g. HLS on the notebook to a usable bitrate, then use the Pi as a viewer - this way you can access the Pi's acceleration hardware and most likely view your video stutter-free.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not competent enough to get the Kodi to stream video files to my raspberry. Especially not when I'm trying to access Paytv via Kodi's plugings...